# How to perform a TRY_CAST in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, casting

I'm try to perform a `TRY_CAST` in SQL Server 2005. The query will look like:

```
SELECT TRY_CAST((select bla bla bla expression) as int)
```

The expression inside the `try_cast` might return some strings or something which cannot be converted as INT, that's why I need it (obviously :) ). Unfortunately I wrote my big query for SQL Server 2012, but now I need to use it on a SQL Server 2005.

Is there a workaround?

Thank you!

Comment: You will need to use TRY/CATCH and/or conditional expressions that test the value before trying to cast it. Those won't be perfect but you can generally tell if a number is not an integer because it doesn't match `'^[0-9]'`, is longer than a certain number of characters, etc.

Comment: Check this link http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6423 should help you

Answer (score 2):

In the end I solved with:

```
case when IsNumeric(Expression)=1
    then cast(Expression as int)
    else NULL
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `ISNUMERIC` answers a different question to what you think. It doesn't answer "Can I cast this expression to an integer?", it answers "Can I cast this expression to *any* of the numeric data types? (Oh, and I don't care which of those data types it can be cast to)". So you'll find `ISNUMERIC('0d0')` is equal to `1` but you'll utterly fail to be able to cast `0d0` to an `int`.

Comment: Adding onto Damien's comment, `ISNUMERIC()` will tell you `'1,5'` is a number (which is true) but casting to a numeric type without the correct codepage will fail.